# Xcode 13 storyboard disappeared

Tags: storyboard, xcode13

When it disappeared, I was unhappily trying to add a field to a menu button on the storyboard. It compiles and runs but I can't see the storyboard anymore.

Answer (score 0):

OK I messed up it was the silly left/right button.